# expected `;' before "cout"

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Hey everyone I am a newbie and would love some help. I got the book called C++ without fear by Brian Overland and I'm following along all the examples but for some reason this happens:

E:\portableapps\Dev-Cpp Portable\App\devcpp\main.cpp In function `int main(int, char**)': 
 9 E:\portableapps\Dev-Cpp Portable\App\devcpp\main.cpp expected`;' before "cout" 
 E:\portableapps\Dev-Cpp Portable\App\devcpp\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [main.o] Error 1

The example in the book says to write the following code and save it then compile and run it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
cout << "I am Blaxxon," <<endl;
cout << "the godlike computer." <<endl;
cout << "Fear me! <<endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

it works fine sometimes in other times I have to write it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
cout << "I am Blaxxon," <<endl;
cout << "the godlike computer." <<endl;
cout << "Fear me! <<endl;

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

otherwise it would show me some errors, which I think is a compiler bug; Dev-C++ portable Beta version.

Anyways the book states that if these characters `<< endl;` are omitted, the program would print

I am Blaxxon, the godlike computer. Fear me!

In a single line, of course. So I try it but I get this error:

E:\portableapps\Dev-Cpp Portable\App\devcpp\print2.cpp In function `int main(int, char**)': 
9 E:\portableapps\Dev-Cpp Portable\App\devcpp\print2.cpp expected`;' before "cout"
 E:\portableapps\Dev-Cpp Portable\App\devcpp\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [print2.o] Error 1

It doesn't print anything in a single like it just show me a systax error. No clue what it is. Any help please.

Comment: Your missing `"` after `"Fear me!`

Comment: Please stop using old, outdated IDEs like Dev-C++. Go use Code::Blocks instead.

Comment: @NicolBolas, surely it's the developers decision which IDE to use. You can recommend an alternative, don't tell them what to use.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko he did say "please"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just forgot the closing quote in

```
cout << "Fear me! << endl;
```

It should be

```
cout << "Fear me!" << endl;
//               ^ notice the closing quote
```

And I thought all IDEs had syntax highlighting.

Comment: Well, Dev-C++ is ancient, so it probably doesn't.

Comment: I already add the " after fear me but it keeps showing me the same error. In order for it to print I need to the <<endl; which is not what I want. I want to print each expression in a single line. which doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @thewikiboy if you want to print them all on the same line, remove the `<<endl` from each print statement, like: `cout << "I am Blaxxon,";
cout << "the godlike computer.";
cout << "Fear me!";` Or you can combine them all into one: `cout << "I am Blaxxon," << "the godlike computer." << "Fear me!";` or just into one long string.

Comment: Thank you @SethCarnegie You explained it better that this book. I just needed to add the ; after each statement, which this book doesn't explain.

Comment: I think the std::endl will add a new line AND send the whole buffer to whatever stream is associated. So to say, you can cout all you want but will eventually have to endl to it get flushed to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You missing an ending `"`

```
cout << "Fear me! " << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

`cout << "Fear me! << endl;`

You're missing a `"` after the string literal.